# Updated requirements - Salesforce formula field evaluating several different values/fields and dates

Tags: formula

if field1 (picklist) **not equal** to value of xxxxx
look at field 2 (date) and if blank or **greater** than today/current date
display value of field 3 (names/text)
if field 3 is blank
display value of field 4 (names/text)
if field 4 is blank
display value of field 5 (names/text)

or
if field1 (picklist) **equal** to value of xxxxx
look at field 2 (date) and if blank or **less** than today/current date
display value of field 4 (names/text)
if field 4 is blank
display value of field 5 (names/text)

Comment: Hi masprosvc, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you **[edit]** your post to explicitly indicate what attempt you have made to solve this problem, as well as including any error messages verbatim, you are much more likely to receive positive attention.

Comment: what kind of values in field1 `picklist` ?

Comment: Values in field1 are (not started, stage 1, stage 2, completed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That formula would look approximately like the following.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Field1, 'xxxxx'),
  NULL,
  IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Field2)), Field2 < TODAY()),
    NULL,
    BLANKVALUE(Field3, Field4)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks 'sfdcfox' that was what I needed to get started...I've completed the formula. Requirements changed a few times. I think I understand how to ask for help on here now. Thanks again all!........Mas